# HTTP_REFERER initiated HTML visible throughout website not just on the initial landing page

Tags: php, http-referer

I have been looking for ever for a solution to my problem - I’m not a PHP newbie but am not overly experienced in it.

My problem is this:

I have a set of sites - one being the parent site. I want to have it so that if I hit any of my child sites from the parent site only, a back to parent button appears (wrapped in a div). If I hit any of the child sites directly or from another referrer then the button doesn't appear.

I have this working using HTTP_REFERER but I would like the button to remain visible when you click the through the site (obviously the referrer changes once I start clicking through the site).

This works for the button appearing on first hitting the site:

```
<?php if (preg_match("~^http://www.mysite.com~i", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {  ?>
<div><a href="http://www.mysite.com/">Back</a></div>
<?php }  ?>
```

But as I say I would like it to remain whilst I am navigating the site - I have looked at setting up a session but I can't get this to work either - the referrer always changes once I start navigating.

I appreciate this is a little vague but I have tried so many code samples and they all seem to have the same issues.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> **Edit:** On closer look, a session based approach might be just enough for this specific situation, if there is only one parent site and multiple children, but no multiple parents! In a more complex situation however, sessions will send you to hell, so I'll leave this answer in place.

This is not trivial -

- you could use sessions to store the referrer target across pages, but that would get confused if the user opens multiple instances of the same page from different referrers, which is horrible for usability
- or send a unique key along with each request that points to the correct "back" target. (It could also be the base64 or URL encoded URL itself, but that would make the URLs look long and ugly...)

The latter is a very clean approach, but a pain to implement consistently.

One other (crazy and untested) idea that comes to mind is storing a base64 encoded representation of the referrer URL using JavaScript in the `window.name` property. The nice thing about that is that unlike a cookie, it stores the "back" target *for the current window only.* I can't guarantee this will work, but it might be worth following up on if you really want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION["ref"])){
    $_SESSION["ref"] = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; //record first instance
} else if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])){
    $ref = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
    if ($ref != $_SESSION["ref"]){
        $_SESSION["ref"] = $ref; // record new ref
    }
}

if ($ref = $_SESSION["ref"]){
    echo "<a href=\"$ref\">Back</a>
}
```

BUT I agree with Pekka, that you should use custom site_id which is passed along whilst you navigate your site. Relaying on `HTTP_REFERER` is generally unsafe. And using session would run you into problem if you come to your master site from two child sites, as session would hold only latest ref.

---

In other solution of ours, we use get param "current_ref", which contains encoded referer url, created by the source site. This param is "sticky", and is passed all along the way, so at any point of time you can return to the originating site. Probably it would be better for you to implement such approach as well.

Comment: yeah. On second read, sessions might be enough for the OP's specific situation though, retracting my comment and +1

Comment: This code seems to work the best/closest. If I land on any of the child sites from the parent site all works as expected (the button appears and remains on the site as I navigate). If however I now I navigate to the child site independently (IE not from my parent) the link doesn't show on the first page that I land on (as it should) but it appears as soon as I start to navigate..

Comment: in your code example does the referrer URL need to referenced? IE does it need to say somewhere www.mysite.com?

Answer (score 1):

Well the HTTP_REFERRER is indeed the last referer of the current page, so you have to store and start a session the first time you enter the site.

Sessions are usually a very simple subject that should work out of the box:

```
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();
if (preg_match("~^http://www.mysite.com~i", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
$_SESSION['parentsite'] = true;
}
```

And later in your code do:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['parentsite']) && $_SESSION['parentsite'] == true){ ?>
<div><a href="http://www.mysite.com/">Back</a></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Now if your sessions still don't work with that, it could be a COOKIE problem or a server configuration problem...

Comment: What if I have three tabs open with the same site but from different referrers? I hate it when sites start acting funny when you are using multiple instances of them (like when browsing through a classifieds site.)

Comment: Well you didn't say you had many different parents, you said you had only one parent and many children sites... I don't think there is any easy solution apart from passing an extra param that allows you to track calls for each page, but then again, my portion about the "session_regenerate_id" will mess up your sessions there if you plan on calling several same children sites from one parent...

Comment: @Matthieu fair enough - this *could* work in the specific situation the OP shows, you're right. (I am not the OP though)

Comment: Yes there is only one parent site but around 5/6 children sites, I have cookies enabled on my browser but it isn't remembering the session - I'm not sure if this would affect it but it is a Wordpress site, I am putting the session code at the very beginning of the header and then calling the session within the HTML of the header file...

Comment: Wordpress trashes the SESSION, GET, POST and COOKIES on each request to manage it with other functions, that i'm sure of cause it happened to me recently in a inhouse catalog+wordpress site. But i don't know more than that, i'm sure you can retrieve the information that its hidding from you but i don'T know how.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as I saw your question I thought that a SESSION would be the key.

You could set a session cookie and then test to see if the cookie already exists.

```
session_start();

if (preg_match("~^http://www.mysite.com~i", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) || 
isset($_SESSION['show_back_button']))
{

    // Set the session value
    $_SESSION['show_back_button'] = true;

    echo '<div><a href="http://www.mysite.com/">Back</a></div>';
}
```

Comment: Does it matter, if you're simply offering a button to redirect back to your main website?  As long as you make it clear about where the link leads too 'Back to Website.com'

Comment: Sorry I’m not sure what you mean? I am trying to make a button appear only from a certain website referrer and be present as I navigate throughout the site The reason I have it in HTML markup is that I have to absolutely position it on the page... Is that what you meant?

Comment: @Darren sorry, it seems that the other user has deleted his comments previous to mine.